# Is there a faster WebView for HTML5 Canvas on Android than PhoneGap?

Tags: android, html, cordova, webview

I use PhoneGap with Android and I have a lot of performance problems on Android devices.

**Is there a faster WebView for HTML5 Canvas on Android than PhoneGap?**

Answer (score 1):

You can continue with phonegap and use the adobe fast canvas plugin.

Or there's Intel Crosswalk that uses latest Chromium and cand be used with Intel XDK.

Comment: The Crosswalk solution solution works great, but it is limited to Android 4.0+ devices.